# MSVC's standard library does not define spaceship operator for std::string, std::shared_ptr, and so?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm trying to make my program multi-platform, originally written for Linux. MSVC (I'm using 19.28) is told to have spaceship operator support from version 19.20 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20), but it seems like it does not define this operator for std::string, or std::shared_ptr (probably for many other beings).

What I'm exactly trying to do is:

```cpp
// int x(1), y(2); // ok!
// std::string x("1"), y("2"); // nope
std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int), y(new int); // nope
auto r = x <=> y; // error C2676 for string and shared_ptr
```

Live example:
https://godbolt.org/z/Eo49hh

It works under GCC 10.2. Am I missing some point in here, or it's not really completely supported?

Comment: Did you set the C++ language standard to `std:c++latest` in the Property page of the project?

Comment: @D-RAJ Yes, also in the live example on godbolt You can see it's set. I've just looked into standard headers for msvc and apparently it's just not defined (opposing to gcc headers). Maybe someone knows any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC supports the `operator<=>`, but that doesn't mean they've implemented for all libraries. From your link to cppreference, under the **C++20 library features** section, it actually shows that MSVC does not have [P1614R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1614r2.html) (*Adding <=> to the standard library*)

It has partial support for [P0768R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0768r1.pdf) (*Library support for operator<=> `<compare>`*) and full support for [P1185R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) (*the operator*)